# Should we use year-end or end-year?

Tags: grammar, word-order, hyphenation, compounds

I wonder that should we use mid-year and year-end or to use mid-year and end-year. What 's diffirent?

Comment: The answer to your title question is general reference: 'mid-year exams' (or rarely, 'middle-of-year exams'), but 'end-of-year exams' or less commonly 'year-end exams'. As to why, perhaps it's because 'end-year' would seem to imply 1918 or 1945 say rather than December, but people feel uncomfortable using 'year-mid' as 'mid' as a noun is virtually obsolete. The pattern occurs also in 'midweek' and 'weekend'.

Comment: In Australia the terms most commonly used would be "mid-year" and "end-of-year" (especially for exams), while the term "year-end" would normally refer specifically to 31 December, except in finance where it could be taken to mean to 30 June, eg "financial year-end figures".

Comment: What's the context??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In financial contexts - I've worked in finance for 25 years - I've never seen anything other than "year-end", e.g. "year-end closing". And analogously: period-end, month-end etc. Sometimes you see it without a hyphen: "year end closing"(Oracle Corp. writes it this way). 
I suppose end-year is grammatically possible and might be used somewhere by someone, but it would definitely be relatively rare.

Answer (score 0):

As an adjective, you'd say "year-end" (e.g., "Please have the year-end reports to me by close of business today.").  However, if you are using it as a noun, we generally say "year's end" (e.g., "We expect to accomplish all of our original goals by year's end.").